# how to dynamically build jq command

Tags: jq

given this input

```
{
  "properties": {
    "hello": [
      "saysay"
    ],
    "test": [
      "1"
    ]
  },
  "uri": "uri"
}
```

I've managed to check whether hello exists using this command

```
curl url | jq 'has("hello")'
```

Now how to check if the value of hello equals to saysay when it is a string variable ?

if hardcoded, below command return true which is expected

```
curl url | jq -r '.properties.hello[]=="saysay"'
```

when i try this one, I've got the following error : (23) Failed writing body

```
curl url | jq -r '.properties.$variable[]=="saysay"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--arg` to set a jq variable from the command line.

```bash
field=hello
curl url | jq --arg property "$field" '.properties[$property][] == "saysay"'
```